# Ajax file upload in node.js

Tags: ajax, file-upload, node.js

I want to upload ajax file upload which uses xhr to send file data,
at client m using this 
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
 how i will accept this data on node and save the file to server by node.js , which module i need to use in node.js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created an uploader with progress bar using the formidable module, it's really easy to use and provides a lot of useful callbacks.

Have a look here:

https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable  (scroll down to get the Docs)

http://debuggable.com/posts/parsing-file-uploads-at-500-mb-s-with-node-js:4c03862e-351c-4faa-bb67-4365cbdd56cb

Comment: Have u created Ajax file upload ?

Comment: I think using XHR (Ajax) to upload a file should work with formidable but uploading files using an XMLHttpRequest is only supported in HTML5 and is not supported by all browsers yet (especially IE)...

Comment: I tried using formidable  but getting error please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988727/ajax-file-upload-in-node-js

Comment: It looks very promising but lacks some HTML file presenting progress bars etc.

Could you please provide one?

Comment: @Jacek Wojcik, the progress bar can be done on the client-side - today I would recommend you to stick with HTML5 file uploads whenever possible, just google it. As an alternative for backward-compatibility a library called plupload might be a good match.

Answer (score 0):

due to the lack of an example file in valums ajax-uploader, I've just created one.

It catches up the XHR upload if possible, alternatively falling back to the old form-based method.
All in conclusion to valums ajax-uploader.

https://github.com/aldipower/file-uploader/blob/master/server/nodejs.js

Maybe Valums will accept the pull request some time and the sample file gets merged in the standard repository.